# How to apply a click function, that changes the clicked div, to new div elements that are created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I am using the following code which on the click of an HTML div element, changes the inner text to "Hello World":

```
<div id = "one" onclick = "click('one')" >text</div>

<script>
    function click(id){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
</script>
```

This works as expected and changes the content of the div to "Hello World".

The problem I am facing is at the moment I am using the id as a parameter input for the function and so that also means that for each div element that I create I would have to manually write its id within the `onclick` function.

I am able to create div elements using the following script which takes a value from an HTML input box, turns into a number then uses that number in a for loop to create as many div elements as specified:

```
<script>
function numberOfDivs(){
    var divValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox").value, 10);
        for(var i = 1; i < divValue + 1; i++){
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            var divText = document.createTextNode("text")
            //newDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "click()");
            newDiv.appendChild(divText);

            var whatIAmAppendingTo = document.getElementById("one");
            whatIAmAppendingTo.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
</script>
```

Now the problem that I having is applying that click() function to any of the new div elements that have just been created so that the click() function only affects the div that I have clicked on. I have included the setAttribute line when I create the new div elements so there is no problem linking it to the click() function.

I believe that there are two options:

-Either create new code within the numberOfDivs() function and use the var i to create an id that would be different for each new div element that I create, since var i increases to a different value each time the for loop repeats.

or

-Rewrite the click() function so that instead of having to use an id paramater I can instead make the function applicable to all div's. I was roughly thinking along the lines of using the 'this' keyword within that code, or anything along those lines so that it applies to only the div element that I click on.

With both of these possible solutions I'm not quite sure how to execute them so it would be great help if someone would be able to give me an example how it works.

Any questions or clarifications feel free to ask.

Comment: Your second script block is missing an ending `}`. It's best, when quoting code you say is working, to use copy-and-paste rather than retyping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I am facing is at the moment I am having to use the id as a parameter input for the function ...

No, you don't; you can pass `this` into your function, which is a reference to the div the click occurred on:

```
<div id = "one" onclick = click(this) >text</div>
```

Then in your function, use that argument rather than `document.getElementById(id)`:

```
function click(div){
    div.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Now you can use the same function for multiple divs.

Note, though, that if you're creating the divs programmatically, there's a better answer than setting the `onclick` attribute: `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on older versions of IE). In your function creating divs:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var divText = document.createTextNode("text")
if (newDiv.addEventListener) {
    newDiv.addEventListener("click", click, false);
}
else {
    newDiv.attachEvent("onclick", click);
}
```

Within `click`, use `this`:

```
function click(){
    this.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typo in innerHTML and onClick
    text

```
<script>
    function click(id){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<div id = "one" onClick ="click('one')" >text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this idea be helpful? Create your divs as (example for `id='one'`):

```
<div class='mydivs' id='one' ></div>
```

And then, detect the click on the div using a class and one event handler using **JQuery**:

```
$(".mydivs").click( function() {
   id = $(this).attr('id');
   click(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="one">
<!-- dynamically added child nodes -->
</div>

<script>
$.ready(function(){
$('#one').children().livequery('click', function(event){
         this.innerHTML = "Hello world";
    });
});
<script>
```

Here we can use [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) to add click handlers to child elements that will be added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

if you provide your newly created divs with a common class e.g. clickable you could do this

```
$function(){
   //Any click event of the body element that originates from a ".clickable" 
   //will be handled by the provided handler
   $("body").on("click",".clickable",function(){
     $(this).html("Hello world");
   });
   //... anything else that has to happen on document ready
});
```